# What does Embeding mean?

Tags: functions

First of all let me give you a definition of embeding.
It is defined like that Let $f:X\to Y$, $f$ is called embeding if $f:X\to f(X)$ is a homeomorphism.
We say $X$ can embedded into $Y$ if $\exists$ an embeding $f:X\to Y$.

I can not understand totally of meaning of this definition. Can anyone explain it simply? Thank all of you for now.

Comment: Btw, now I see that $\mathbb R$ can be embeded into $[0,1]$. Because, $\mathbb R$ is isomorphic with $(0,1)$ which is the subset of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Okay okay. I think when I wrote the question in here then I understand the meaning of this.